# python 3 finding and printing integers from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

My text file is laid out like this:

```
1,jack,Jackson,16,won

2,Dex,Craz,17,loss

3,Bree,Lopson,20,

4,her,ber,12,loss

5,say,huy,34,

6,lol,asw,23,won

7,dert,ker,30,loss

8,far,sas,11,

9,ger,xza,15,

10,yui,caer,66,won

11,opl,guyh,45,
```

and what I'm trying to do is have the user input a number that they would like to see and print out the information corresponding to that number.

This is my code:

```
numb = input('Input Line: ')
fiIn = open('Prac.txt').readlines()
for lines in fiIn:
   if numb == lines[0]:
      data = lines.split(',')
      print ('|{0[0]:<15}|{0[1]:<15}|{0[2]:<15}|{0[3]:<15}|{0[4]:<15}'.format(data))
```

but it doesn't only print the number I want but also other numbers.
For example: if I input 1 it would output 1, 10 and 11 not just 1.
Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` `lines` first, then check if the first item is your number.

```
for lines in fiIn:
   data = lines.split(',')
   if numb == data[0]:
       print ('|{0[0]:<15}|{0[1]:<15}|{0[2]:<15}|{0[3]:<15}|{0[4]:<15}'.format(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the comparison line `if numb == lines[0]:` where you are checking the input string with the first character of the line and hence it matches all the lines starting with `1`, What you need to do is split the line on `,` and then compare the first element as :

```
numb = input('Input Line: ')
fiIn = open('Prac.txt').readlines()
for lines in fiIn:
   if numb == lines.split(",")[0]:
      data = lines.split(',')
      print ('|{0[0]:<15}|{0[1]:<15}|{0[2]:<15}|{0[3]:<15}|{0[4]:<15}'.format(data))
```